# Django return render to datatable from edit view (or refhesh page to show uptated datatable)

Tags: python, django, redirect, return, render

I have a template that shows me a datatable, for each record a button that edits/delete the record through a form, sends it to a view and saves it.
I need it to return me to the same template that has the table with the updated data.
Currently it redirects me to the template but without showing me the datatable

- With **return redirect** it returns me to the original page without showing me anything
- With **return render** it shows me the datatable, but it changes the URL

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my English, I'm a junior

View

```
def delete_itemresumen(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
    .....
    .....
    .....

    coleccion = Auxiliarresumen.objects.filter(
            Q(mes__icontains=mes) & Q(anio__icontains=anio) & Q(codcuentabanco=codban)
        ).distinct()


     form = RegistroBuscarResumen(initial={'accion':'buscar',  'id_codcuentabanco':codban,      
'id_periodo':camp2})
 


    return redirect("/bancos/procesarresumen")
  
    #or
  
    return render(request, 'bancos/procesarresumen.html', {'form': form, 'colecc': coleccion})
```

And HTML

```
{% if colecc %}
      
      <table id="Listaitems" class="table table-hover table-sm text-left" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;" >
      
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">Concepto</th>
            <th scope="col">Subconcepto</th>
            <th scope="col">Observacion</th>
            <th scope="col">Importe</th>
            <th scope="col">C/D</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                          
          </tr>
        </thead>
          
        <tbody center>
          {% for col_obj in colecc %}
            <tr>
              <!-- <td<th scope="row">{{col_obj.fecha}}</th> -->
              
              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.fecha}}</td>

              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.codsubconcepto.codconcepto.descripcion}}</td>

              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.codsubconcepto.descripcion}}</td>
              
              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.descripcion}}</td>
              
              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.importe}}</td>

              <td class="h5 small">{{col_obj.tipo}}</td>
              
              <th>
                
                
                
                <button id="id_editaritem2" type="button" class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick="Func_Edit('{{ col_obj.coddetalle }}')" ><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Editar</button>
              </div>
              </th> 
                           
            </tr>
          {% empty %}
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center">No tasks yet</h1>
          {% endfor %}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
```